# pipenv cant install django

Tags: python, django, pip, pipenv

So I just recently got into coding, and I'm using pipenv to set up a virtual environment and trying to install django in the virtual environment. I'm using python 3.6.4, but have tried installing with 3.5 as well and get the same error. After running 'pipenv install django' I get this error:

```
Installing django…
Collecting django
Using cached Django-2.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from django)
Using cached pytz-2018.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pytz, django
Successfully installed django-2.0.3 pytz-2018.3

Adding django to Pipfile's [packages]…
Pipfile.lock (711973) out of date, updating to (220011)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
raise SSLError(e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 82, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 71, in main
clear=do_clear,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 63, in resolve
verbose=verbose,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 471, in resolve_deps
timeout=10,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm new to linux and development in general, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've hit [this bug](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1800) in pipenv. It's been fixed in the master branch but I’m not sure whether there has been a release since then.

Comment: Thanks, uninstalling and reinstalling pipenv did the trick for me.